# nextauth js , nextJS app dir: how do I check if user has completed onBoarding in middleware. Unable to get userSession in middleware

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I am using nextauth.js along with app dir to authenticate my nextjs app.
I am trying to build an onBoarding page where the user needs to enter the username before proceeding to the onboarding page.

My middleware.js

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";


async function getUserSession() {

const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
console.log(session)
}

getUserSession()

//Once I get the session I will write the logic to check if onboarding has been completed from the flag value in the mongoDB table



//routes to include and exclude for authentication
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!|api|login).*)", "/", "/onBoarding"],
};
```

However I get an error If I try to import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

Through the

```
pages: {
newUser: /onBoarding}
```

I can successfully redirect users to onBoarding on first-time login. However, I want to check from the middleware if the user has already completed onboarding. How do I check from the middleware if the onboarding has been completed?